# Restricting Taxonomy vocabulary for lower roles

Tags: drupal

This seems like a simple question but I forget.

When you have a low access role like a member, and want to only show a particular vocabulary on a node form, what controls this? Is it a contrib module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put access control on the form item itself. Not sure if there is a module for it to make it easier.